# Xtext Validation for a DSL

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I have some grammer in xtext which looks like this
.xtext file

```
grammar org.xtext.example.cytosim.Cytosim with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate cytosim "http://www.xtext.org/example/cytosim/Cytosim"

Model:
   entitys += Entity* runs+= Run ; 

 
Entity :
    'entity' name=ID '{'
    fields += Field*
    '}'
;

Field:
 'field' name=ID
;


Run :
    'run' name=ID '{'
    frames += Frame*
    '}'
;

Frame:
 'frames' name=ID
;
```

This will allow me to type this in the editor when i run this which produces

```
entity A {
    field x
}

entity B {
    field s
}

run AB{
    frames k
}
```

First my qyestion is it possible to add two prametres after the 'entity, or 'run' parameter. For example 'run AB CD', with them being two diffrent parameters.

Also how will i modify the xtext or other files, so when i type 'entity' or 'run' the ID that is associated with it is from a predefined list.
In the bove example i have 'run AB' ....

But i want the ID ("AB", in this case) to be ethier CD or EF. If anything else is typed in, the error message pops up.

Comment: Where does this "predefined list" comes from? If it's part of the language you can include it right into your grammar (e.g. replace `'run' name=ID` with `run name=AllowedId`; AllowedId being a new rule you'd have to define). Otherwise you can check run's name in your Xtext validator and provide a custom autocomplete (see _Quick Fixes_ and _Content Assist_ sections [in the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html)).

Comment: And yes, you can add multiple parameters after 'entity' or 'run', just try it out: `'run' name=ID otherParam=ParamRule`

Comment: Thank you, the multiple parameters soloution worked fine and also the predefined list was from my language and i could just add this into my grammer.  By adding "AnotherID: 'a'|'A'|'_'*;" just under Model. @EmmanuelChebbi